# Python3, no module named pysvn on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysvn

On my Ubutntu machine i have both python 2.7 and 3.5. I've installed pysvn according tointruction [here](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html)

```
sudo apt-get install python-svn
sudo apt-get install svn-workbench
```

Python 2.7 sees it, but not 3.5:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysvn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pysvn'
>>>
```

Comment: what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: That's because you've installed the Python 2 package. You should start using conda or venvs.

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: Install python3-svn